# Poker rules: opening the fifth card

Tags: rules

If last 2 players show their cards before opening the 5th card. Then do we open the 5th card and will that be evaluated?

Comment: Why are they showing their cards, are they all in?

Answer (score 0):

First you would only turn your hole cards face up if both players are all in

Yes you would run the board to the fifth card

Winning hand is always based on best 5 cards from the 2 hole cards plus the shared board of 5 cards